# Get Text of Node(Item) Treeview in SelectedItemChange Event IN WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

First of all I am from Iran and I can't speak English very well, sorry for this.
I made something like `OpenFileDialog` in WinForms and it works correctly.

After that for better User Interface I'm try to make it in WPF.

I use `TreeView` and other controls to make it work in both platforms (Winforms and WPF).

In WPF I want to get the text of `Treeview` item for comparison, in Winform I could do this with below code:

```
private void Folder_FileTreeView_NodeMouseDoubleClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{

     if(e.Node.Text=="Desktop")
     {
        //Do something
     }

}
```

in WPF I added text with and image next to each other using this method:

```
public object Node(string NodeIMGUri, string NodeText)
{

                Image IMG = new Image() { Source = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri(NodeIMGUri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)) };
                TextBlock Text = new TextBlock() { Text = NodeText };
                StackPanel CustomStackPanel = new StackPanel();
                TreeViewItem TVItem = new TreeViewItem();
                IMG.Height = 50;
                IMG.Width = 50;
                CustomStackPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
                CustomStackPanel.Children.Add(IMG);
                CustomStackPanel.Children.Add(Text);
                TVItem.Header = CustomStackPanel;
                return TVItem;
            }
```

But when in `SelectedItemChanged` (or `ItemChanged`) event of `TreeView` how can I get the text of the item clicked?

If anyone can help me to complete this dll, I can send it free to all programmers.

This dll supports most languages like german, france, china, hindi, bengali, indonesian, persian, japanese, korean, arabic, portuguese, latin, swede, english

[image: 1]

Comment: This is really bad code. If you plan to continue to work with WPF you should really take a look on data binding which ca be used with WinForms as well. The way you code the UI is overly complicated and error prone. If you want it clean and easy because simple then check data binding and view models. You usually create a data structure that represents the tree structure of the filesystem. You then bind this data structure to the `TreeView.ItemsSource` which will generate the view automatically for you. `DataTemplates` are there to customize the default appearance.

Comment: Doing it this way, the `TreeView.SelectedItem` property would hold the information you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are currently doing things, you would need to go through the children of your item to find the `TextBlock` and get the `Text` property from that. But this isn't the proper or recommended way of doing things in WPF.

Instead of manually creating `TreeViewItem`s, you shoudl be using `TreeView.ItemsSource` and `TreeView.ItemTemplate`. If you're not familiar with how to use `DataTemplate`s in WPF, you should really read up on it. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview) is a good place to start.

Basically you would define a class, let's say `Folder`, then you would have a collection of `Folder` objects (e.g. `List<Folder>`), and you would bind that to `TreeView.ItemsSource`. You would then use a `DataTempalte` to declare the visual representation of how a `Folder` object should look in the `TreeView`. Then, when the selected item is changed, you can use `TreeViewItem.DataContext` to get the `Folder` object that is being selected, which would probably have a property such as `Path`.

Answer (score -1):

So what I can see there you put into your TreeViewItem's header a panel with two items - Image and TextBlock with **Text** you want to get. The TextBlock is stored as the second item in the panel's collection (Children). All you have to do is this:

```
private void TreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    CustomStackPanel panel = (CustomStackPanel)((TreeViewItem) e.NewValue).Header;
    TextBlock textBlock = (TextBlock)panel.Children[1];

    string text = textBlock.Text; //Your text
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks A lot  "Pawleshhh"

 before i have this code  ```                                                                   CustomStackPanel panel = (CustomStackPanel)((TreeViewItem) e.NewValue).Header;
    TextBlock textBlock = (TextBlock)panel.Children[1];

    string text = textBlock.Text; i use Treeview.Items.Clear()  i get null ,and i need to clear my tree view could you help to use above code with clearing before items and get text and compare for add Item forexample when i click  document ,first page clear and get text (without null) for add item